# App stopped working from one day to another with no changes

Tags: flutter, dart, initializing

I was hoping you could guide me in some direction since im totally lost. Today i opened my project on vs code, and it just gets stuck on initializing flutter forever. So i start the project via flutter run on the console. And i get this error message.

I should also point out that this problem persists regardless of the project i try to run.

I tried changing the gradle version zip file in gradle wrapper properties file , also re downloading the current version of the project and pasting it in the dists /.gradle/wrapper/folder, but the problem persists

```
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/build_runner/devfs_web.dart:97:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'WebAssetServer' is missing implementations for these members:
 - AssetReader.metadataContents
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
 
class WebAssetServer implements AssetReader {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dwds-5.1.0/lib/src/readers/asset_reader.dart:18:18: Context: 'AssetReader.metadataContents' is defined here.        
  Future<String> metadataContents(String serverPath);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/test/coverage_collector.dart:69:16: Error: The argument type 'Future<Map<String, Map<int, int>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, Map<int, int>>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
    _addHitmap(coverage.createHitmap(data['coverage'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>));
               ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/test/coverage_collector.dart:101:16: Error: The argument type 'Future<Map<String, Map<int, int>>>' can't be assigned to 
the parameter type 'Map<String, Map<int, int>>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
    _addHitmap(coverage.createHitmap(data['coverage'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>));
               ^
Error: Unable to create dart snapshot for flutter tool.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgrade your Flutter to the latest version, most likely some of you packages might not be updated anymore.

- Go check each of the package in pubspec.yaml and check if you need to update any of them.
- You will need to check if there are any Breaking Changes on the documentation as well.